# How to stop flow from observer in Magento2 without using die or exit?

Tags: magento2, debugging, event-observer

I have a custom observer and I am intercepting calls in some situation I want to return some specific data and prevent Magento to proceed with its flow, how can I achieve this without using die or exit in Magento 2?

my event.xml is like :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
      <observer name="my_observer" instance="MyObserver" shared="false" />
  </event>
</config>
```

and my cobserver looks like

```
class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
  public function __construct(
  \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
  \Magento\Framework\App\State $state)
  {

  }
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
    $action = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
    //if(X exist in cookie)
            {
                $response = $action->getResponse();
        $response->setRedirect($result->redirectUrl)->sendResponse();
                return;
            }
    else if(Y exist in cookie)
       {

                $response->setHeader('YResult', 'Y Result');
        //Send for example empty body from here to client and prevent Magento 2 to continue
       }
    else
        {
        //Do nothing continue normal flow
        }

  }
}
```

in the first if I was able to send redirect header and stop the normal flow by

```
$response->setRedirect($result->redirectUrl)->sendResponse();
```

but for the second if I do not want response with redirect, I want to send empty a response with a custom header (custom javascript on client side will pick up the answer and react to it  )

Comment: can you please add your code and give more detail about event and condition.

Comment: try throwing an exeption :) it worked for me on M1.9.x worth a shot on the M2 too.

Answer (score 1):

Observers are not supposed to use for stop flow. Use plugins instead